# How can I fix the type errors for applying reduce on a MutableList of MutableSets to find the intersections of all sets?

Tags: generics, kotlin, collections

I'd like to find the intersections of `a`, `b` and `c`. Since I want to add more sets to the `lst`-object in the future, I defined it as a MutableList.

```
var a = mutableSetOf(1, 2, 3)
var b = mutableSetOf(2, 3, 4)
var c = mutableSetOf(3, 4, 5)
var lst = mutableListOf(a, b, c)

var intersection = lst.reduce {
    acc, currSet -> acc.intersect(currSet)
}
```

However, the last expression raises "invalid" due to failed type inference. (check [this](https://pl.kotl.in/qbjCWo3J6) playground)

From the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reduce.html) I have the following signature for the `reduce` operation:

```
inline fun <S, T : S> Iterable<T>.reduce(
    operation: (acc: S, T) -> S
): S
```

So why can't `S` and `T` be of the same type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need to use "Mutable" types here? It would work with non-mutable sets:

```
val a = setOf(1, 2, 3)
val b = setOf(2, 3, 4)
val c = setOf(3, 4, 5)
val lst = listOf(a, b, c)

val intersection = lst.reduce { acc, currSet -> 
    acc.intersect(currSet)
}
```

The problem is that `intersect` returns a `Set`, rather than a `MutableSet`, which makes the type check unhappy. Fixable by using `acc.intersect(currSet).toMutableSet()` in the `reduce` lambda or changing to `acc: Set<Int>`. I'd always go with immutable types, and prefer the code I posted above.

Nit: prefer `val` over `var`.

Comment: In my original code I'm also adding elements to the sets. I was aware that there is `toMutableList`, but unfortunately my brain did not manage to make the connection to sets haha. I see, I will make sure to check the function types next time. Thank you!